# Purple object, UV wrapping

Tags: uv, node-editor, shaders

[image]I am creating a uv wrap around my doughnut, I go to the shading section to add nodes to create a texture to the doughnut. After I link the noise texture, image texture, texture coordinate and displacement the doughnut turns purple. I have tried finding the missing files, made sure I was in cycles, adding the image to another file, and relinking all of the nodes and nothing has worked so far. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please add screenshots of your material setup and your result of the pink donut.

Comment: The pink color is basically a result of “no data found.” More likely than not, you have forgotten to put an output node in your shader setup, especially if the doughnut appears to be glowing.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I've tried connecting different nodes and doesn't work?